# How to change a .eps figure to standalone class?

Tags: standalone, epstopdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.7]{Luke.eps}
\caption{Digraph.}
\label{fig:digraph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Link file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pyfhk4okehvs99gCGNHqtfqJrpqbvmoL)

Question: I want to use `standalone` class for it. How can I do?

It works with Skillmoon's answer:

```
\documentclass[preview,border={-100pt 5pt -100pt 3pt}]{standalone}
```

Comment: Replace `article` with `standalone`. If you want to use a caption, use the class option `preview`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have your file (and will not download it for this). The following should work:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-image-a}
\caption{Digraph.}
\label{fig:digraph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```